# Create proxy server Socket hang up (HTTPS)

Tags: node.js, meteor, proxy

Hi I'm using meteor and http-proxy from node js. I got this error sometimes

```
W20160526-08:53:02.348(7)? (STDERR) 
W20160526-08:53:02.350(7)? (STDERR) /usr/local/bin/here_test/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy/index.js:119
W20160526-08:53:02.350(7)? (STDERR)     throw err;
W20160526-08:53:02.426(7)? (STDERR)           ^
W20160526-08:53:02.429(7)? (STDERR) Error: socket hang up
W20160526-08:53:02.429(7)? (STDERR)     at createHangUpError (http.js:1528:15)
W20160526-08:53:02.430(7)? (STDERR)     at Socket.socketCloseListener (http.js:1578:23)
W20160526-08:53:02.430(7)? (STDERR)     at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
W20160526-08:53:02.430(7)? (STDERR)     at TCP.close (net.js:466:12)
```

Since I don't get any answers from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052874/node-js-proxy-server-socket-hang-up), so I ask in my own post. 
this is my proxy code

```
var PATH_TO_KEY = "/usr/local/bin/here_test/here.enseval.com.key",  
    PATH_TO_CERT = "/usr/local/bin/here_test/star_enseval_com(3).pem";
    //PATH_TO_CHAIN = "";

var fs = require('fs'),  
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var options = {  
  ssl: {    
    key: fs.readFileSync(PATH_TO_KEY, 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(PATH_TO_CERT, 'utf8')
    //ca : fs.readFileSync(PATH_TO_CHAIN, 'utf8')
  },
  target : "http://here.enseval.com",
  secure:true,
  ws:true,
  xfwd: true 
};

var server = httpProxy.createProxyServer(options).listen(443);
```

I already use `ws:true` according to this [website](http://zacharywolffs.ghost.io/2015/01/08/setting-up-node-js-https-proxy/) but still I got that randomly errors.

Anyone can help me?

thank you

Comment: Maybe you just have an unstable connection to that "target" or your proxy server? "Socket hang up" means the connection failed somehow. In Meteor it should even reopen automatically.

Comment: okay I get it, but every time the error "socket hang up" appear, i should restart manually by enter the PEM password. Do you know how to automatically enter the PEM password when the server restart??

Comment: I assume `PEM password` has something to do with ssh? Then you can run the `ssh-agent`. It will store your key in memory until you need to restart your server.

Comment: Well I tried to use ssh-agent according to this [article](http://www.beginninglinux.com/home/server-administration/openssh-keys-certificates-authentication-pem-pub-crt). I Only use this comment on that article `$ ssh -i ~/ec2.pem ubuntu@12.34.56.78`
but the "socket hang up" error still appear and the meteor server was restart so I must enter the PEM password manually again. I'm sure the connection is stable.

Comment: I don't really get where you type in that password. the agent doesn't crash because of a failed socket. You sure, you run Meteor inside the agent and are you sure the agent is used for the ssh session? Your connection is not stable, "the other side" closes it quite rude. ;) If Meteor crashes because of this uncaught exception, try catching it by `socket.on('error', ...)` or worst case `process.on('uncaughtException',...`. Maybe that helps?